# Python Import Camelot module not found inside custom IDE

Tags: python, python-camelot

I am using a customized scripting environment and attempting to convert a pdf file using [Camelot](https://camelot-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/) for Python v. 3.7.4.

When I run the script from the command line in Windows, it works as expected.  When I run the script from inside the custom IDE, I get an error related to the `import Camelot` line, which says "Camelot module not found."

I do know there is a folder for the custom IDE where I should place .py files for importing.  The problem is the only file I can find for Camelot in my file structure is a `camelot.exe` file.  Does anyone know what .py file actually gets imported for the `import Camelot` command?

Answer (score 1):

Your ide probably use another python version, or even a virtual env to execute the file, check those configuration, it proabably what makes the problem

check that the python executable is the same as in the cmd you are running

Comment: may also be the case sensitivity "camelot" ?